# Laravel Called to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel

i get the following error when i navigate in my browser to the following route: example.com/api/test

"Call to undefined method App\Http\Controllers\Controller::getRandomRequestID()"

api.php content

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as controller;

Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
    return controller::getRandomRequestID();
});
```

controller.php content

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
    //laravel 8 php 8.1
    public static function getRandomRequestID(): string
    {
        return Str::random(32);
    }
}
```

System Informations:
Laravel version: 8.83.26
Laravel config cached: false
PHP version: 8.1.12

APP:
Routing
Controller: Closure
Route name: unknown
Route parameters: —
Middleware: api

I don't know why the error is coming

When i add the function direct to the api.php it's works but not when i have the function in the controller.php

Comment: Despite seemingly being called statically, your method should be declared without `static`

Comment: public function getRandomRequestID(): string
    {
        return Str::random(32);
    }
getting the same error

Comment: Flare:https://flareapp.io/share/KPg3b1ZP

Comment: I tried the code and it works !!